# How to create subelements with conditions in list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

I'm trying to get a new list with elements separated in sublist for following conditions:

1-) Separate in sublists the sequences from 1 to N (N in this case is 3)

2-) Separate in sublists the sequences from 1 to N even there are missing numbers between 1 and N

3-) Separate in sublists the rest elements

The expected output would be like this.

```
b = [[3], [2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

My current attempt is below but is associating incorrectly the elements. Thanks for any help

```
b = [None]*len(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if 1 not in a[i][0]:
        b[i] = [a[i]]
```

Comment: If "a" is always like this, and N is always 3, then I think it's fastest for you to just hand write the answer

Comment: N could be =>3 and <=15

Comment: @RasecMalkic I just want to know if your list is like this: `a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]`, what result do you want to get?

Comment: @911 Hi, if `a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]` , then output would be `[[3], [2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [3], [2], [2, 3], [2], [1, 3], [1, 2]]`. In this case `N = 4`

Comment: @RasecMalkic So is N always the largest number in the list? Then what are the "rest elements" of condition 3?

Comment: @KellyBundy Hi, "Rest elements" are the ones that are isolated "alone". In others words, sublists with more than one element happens when you find a sequence from X to Y, where X = 1,2,3...,N-1 and Y=2,3,..,N etc. even when there are missing numbers in between that sequence. The rest are numbers without any sequence, in other ways "alone". I hope make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new sub-list to the output when the current item is not greater than the last item of the last sub-list of the output:

```
a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]
n = 3

output = []
for i in a:
    if not output or not 1 <= output[-1][-1] < i <= n:
        output.append([])
    output[-1].append(i)
```

`output` becomes:

```
[[3], [2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FavoriteLargeSite

Answer (score 1):

To understand the logic in a simple way

```
#YOUR LIST
a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2]

#YOUR LIST OF LISTS
finalList = [] 

#TEMPORAY LIST
tempList = []
size = len(a)

#LOGIC
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (i+1 < size) and  (a[i] < a[i+1]):
        tempList.append(a[i])
    else:
        tempList.append(a[i])
        finalList.append(tempList[:]) #NO REFERENCE.
        tempList.clear()

print(finalList)
```